# fgets is reading in too late

Tags: c, fgets

Okay. After having completely rewritten this program over in favor of fgets, it mostly reads in the words.

This comes in two pieces, compiled upon a gcc linux machine. However, a redirect statement is required for this.

So once compiled it must be run like this:

```
./a.out < data1
```

So here's "data1":

```
S T E L B M T F E Y D E E P S R T C I A E E 
N N E L I T R L B D E T A R E M U N E T Y L 
N O I T A N I M I R C N I F L E S S E N T A 
A U I D E W A R R A N T N U P R U S S E R P 
P G S G E A L P A P B A N P S A S S N M E A 
C O N S I T U T I O N D E E C W S O O H P D 
S V W D E L A N E E J A M E S M A D I S O N 
A E D E S N E G R J C U L T N O H L T I R A 
A R C E R R T R E E S B O N E E I D N N P R 
S N J U D I C I A L A S S E C O R P E U D I 
S M R A R A E B W B E S S M E O A U V P E M 
O E O I A I L N O U C D O D S S E N N I G R 
L N I D G Y T R C O M P E N S A T I O N N D 
D T O Z E H P Y N D R L E E A O H S C O I B 
I T P S U E T G O L U Z M M R B E H P I R T 
E O I E A R R S U U I B H A Y L L M S T F A 
R I N R E E E F U T L V Q U A R T E R I N G 
S I D B S R R D I Y E N I G M I A N A T I R 
S Q I S E B S C N S P E E C H R O T A E Y N 
D L C M I L I T I A F L R N C A T S S P S E 
R U T E D Y L E B I L C O H M L E T E S Y Y 
L S T R T E W Z L I O S A E N S A E I Y A L 
AMENDMENT
ASSEMBLY
BAIL
BEARARMS
CITIZEN
CIVIL
COMPENSATION
CONGRESS
CONSITUTION
CONVENTIONS
DELEGATED
DOUBLEJEOPARDY
DUEPROCESS
ENUMERATED
FREEDOM
GOVERNMENT
ILLEGAL
INDICT
INFRINGED
JAMESMADISON
JUDICIAL
LAWSUIT
LIBEL
LIBERTY
LIFE
MILITIA
MIRANDA
NECESSARY
PEACEABLY
PEERS
PETITION
POWER
PRESS
PROBABLECAUSE
PROPERTY
PUNISHMENTS
QUARTERING
RELIGION
RIGHTS
SEARCH
SECURITY
SEIZURE
SELFINCRIMINATION
SLANDER
SOLDIERS
SPEECH
SPEEDY
TRIAL
UNREASONABLE
WARRANT
WITNESS
```

Here's the program itself:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ROWS 50
#define COLUMNS 50
#define TR 100
#define TC 100

int main( )
{
    int s1 = 0, s2 = 0;
    int sizeOfGrid = 0;
    int wordCount = 0;
    int rowNumber = 0;
    int colNumber = 0;
    /* */
    char tempLetters[ROWS][COLUMNS];
    char letters[ROWS][COLUMNS];
    char words[ROWS][COLUMNS];
    char wordTemp[50];
    char firstRow[100], nextRow[100];
    /* fgets(stdin); */
    char firstRowTemp[100], nextRowTemp[100];
    /* output       input */

    setbuf(stdout, NULL);

    for (s2 = 0; s2 < 100; s2++)
    {
        firstRowTemp[s2] = ' ';
        nextRowTemp[s2] = ' ';


        if (s2 < 50)
        {
            wordTemp[s2] = ' ';
            for (s1 = 0; s1 < 50; s1++)
            {
                words[s2][s1] = ' ';
            }
        }
    }

    /* Let's attempt to despace the first line, and then count the chars. */
    fgets(firstRow,100,stdin);
    s1 = 0;
    s2 = 0;
    for (colNumber = 0; colNumber < strlen(firstRow); colNumber++)
    {
        if ((firstRow[colNumber] != ' ') && (firstRow[colNumber] != '\n'))
        {
            firstRowTemp[s1] = firstRow[colNumber];
            letters[rowNumber][s2++] = firstRowTemp[s1++];
            sizeOfGrid++;
        }
    }

    /* We have now successfully gotten the size of the grid, so lets
     * put it to good use within our next loops to read in the rest
     * of the lines.
     * We take it in a for loop up to sizeOfGrid*2 because right now,
     * we still have spaces. Once we get rid of those, it'll be able to utilize
     * normal sizeOfGrid count.*/
    for (rowNumber = 1; rowNumber < sizeOfGrid*2; rowNumber++)
    {
        fgets(nextRow, 100, stdin);
        s1 = 0;
        s2 = 0;
        for (colNumber = 0; colNumber < sizeOfGrid*2; colNumber++)
        {
            if ((nextRow[colNumber] != ' ') && (tempLetters[rowNumber][colNumber] != '\n'))
            {
                nextRowTemp[s1] = nextRow[colNumber];
                letters[rowNumber][s2++] = nextRowTemp[s1++];
            }
        }
    }

    /* Next up, it's time to store the words. Scan the rest of the file for words
     * and store them as chars. */

    rowNumber = 0;
    colNumber = 0;

    while(fgets(wordTemp,50,stdin) != NULL)
    {
        for (s1 = 0; s1 < strlen(wordTemp); s1++)
        {
            if (wordTemp[s1] != '\n')
            {
                words[rowNumber][colNumber++] = wordTemp[s1];
            }

        }
        colNumber = 0;
        wordCount++;
        rowNumber++;
    }

    /* For testing purposes and making sure it receives the grid entirely.*/

    for (s2 = 0; s2 < sizeOfGrid; s2++)
    {
        printf("%c",firstRowTemp[s2]);
    }
    printf("\nSize of grid is %d\n",sizeOfGrid);
    printf("\n");
    for (rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < sizeOfGrid; rowNumber++)
    {
        for (colNumber = 0; colNumber < sizeOfGrid; colNumber++)
        {
            printf("%c", letters[rowNumber][colNumber]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (rowNumber = 0; rowNumber < ROWS; rowNumber++)
    {
        for (colNumber = 0; colNumber < COLUMNS; colNumber++)
        {
            if ((words[rowNumber][colNumber] != ' ') && (words[rowNumber][colNumber] != '\n'))
                printf("%c", words[rowNumber][colNumber]);
            else
                break;
        }
        if (colNumber > 1)
            printf("\n");
    }

    /* End print debugging here.*/

    return 0;
}
```

And now for my question itself...

It appears fgets is skipping over a large number of words, starting only at LIBEL instead of running through the top of the list (AMENDMENTS in this case). Where is it going wrong?

Comment: Minor: Suggest rather than `fgets(firstRow,100,stdin);`, consider `fgets(firstRow, sizeof firstRow,stdin);`.  Its less error prone and easier to maintain.  (Also `fgets(nextRow, 100, stdin);`)

Comment: The comment about `sizeOfGrid*2` seems to be telling you exactly what to do. There are no blank lines, so you're reading twice as many lines as you should. Also you misspelled constitution

Comment: Maybe no limit in `while(fgets(wordTemp,50,stdin)` loop for `rowNumber` and `words[rowNumber][colNumber++]` grows beyond 50?

Comment: The words[][] is not limited nor used in conjunction with the sizeOfGrid. The sizeOfGrid is meant only for the box of letters. The words go somewhere else entirely.

Comment: On the plus side, "consitution" is also spelled so in the puzzle.

Comment: @WumpusQ. Qumbley: You were right. That fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: The way to indicate that your problem is solved is to accept an answer, not to update the title. In this case, since @WumpusQ.Wumbley's comment appears to have solved it, he or she should post an answer, which you could then accept.

Comment: Nobody had put an "answer" down when I posted this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the grid you've shown us, there are spaces between letters horizontally, but no blank lines between the lines of letters, so you need to use `sizeOfGrid*2` to loop over the columns, but not the rows.